# How to run camunda on Apple silicon

Tags: docker, camunda, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I'm trying to setup camunda with docker in my local,
I'm getting the message below.

-- WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested

- docker pull camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:run-latest
- docker run -d --name camunda -p 8080:8080 camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:run-latest

I can not be reached http://localhost:8080 or http://localhost:8080 on Camunda.
Do you have any advice, also I using Apple MacBook m1.

Comment: Excuse me, but this question has nothing to do with Apple silicon, but that you forgot to run the command in docker. Can you please edit the whole question to match the problem? Or even delete the question as the problem was "forgetting" to run something which wouldn't help anyone I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can extend the base image with your own Dockerfile and specify the platform in the FROM command
just put this at the top

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:run-latest
... any other customization you want goes here
```

then just use your docker image instead of the wanna pulled from camunda registry

takes a bit longer to start up than it did on intel mac but seems to work.

see docker docs re: the `platform=` arg

Answer (score 1):

I tried some things, and if you don't run the Camunda or do not reach anything in the browser about Camunda welcome page.

Download Camunda source file (.zip), then extract it.
you can run the start.sh file
and for now, I was able to login the Camunda panel in my MacBook (m1-Apple silicon)
but, it still doesn't run in docker.

Comment: $ alias camunda=./start.sh
and run $ camunda